# How to sequentially run promises with Q in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I am having a hard time running promises sequentially.

```
var getDelayedString = function(string) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    setTimeout(function() {
        document.write(string+" ");
        deferred.resolve();
    }, 500);

    return deferred.promise;
};

var onceUponATime = function() {
    var strings = ["Once", "upon", "a", "time"];

    var promiseFuncs = [];

    strings.forEach(function(str) {
        promiseFuncs.push(getDelayedString(str));
    });

    //return promiseFuncs.reduce(Q.when, Q());
    return promiseFuncs.reduce(function (soFar, f) {
        return soFar.then(f);
    }, Q());    
};

getDelayedString("Hello")
.then(function() {
    return getDelayedString("world!")
})
.then(function() {
    return onceUponATime();
})
.then(function() {
    return getDelayedString("there was a guy and then he fell.")
})
.then(function() {
    return getDelayedString("The End!")
})
```

onceUponATime() should sequentially output ["Once", "upon", "a", "time"] but instead they are being output immediately for some reason.

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6Du42/2/

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> but instead they are being output immediately for some reason.

You are calling them already here:

```
promiseFuncs.push(getDelayedString(str));
//                                ^^^^^
```

You would need to push `function(){ return getDelayedString(str); }`. Btw, instead of using pushing to an array in an `each` loop you rather should use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). And actually you don't really need that anyway but can `reduce` over the `strings` array directly:

```
function onceUponATime() {
    var strings = ["Once", "upon", "a", "time"];

    return strings.reduce(function (soFar, s) {
        return soFar.then(function() {
            return getDelayedString(s);
        });
    }, Q());    
}
```

Oh, and [don't use `document.write`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and additional hints!

Comment: yeah, it has to be a function *factory* to work, otherwise it executes immediately.