# Serialize a list of js promises call

Tags: javascript, promise, q

what's the most convenient way to serialize a bunch of promised function call?

```
var promised_functions = [
 fn1,  // call this 
 fn2,  // if previous resolved call this
 fn3   // if previous resolved call this
];
q.serialize_functions(promised_functions)
.then(function(){
 // if all promises resolved do some
})
```

Comment: take a look to this question. I may found your answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386753/how-to-sequentially-run-promises-with-q-in-javascript

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can find the solution in the [documentation](https://npmjs.org/package/q):

```
promised_functions.reduce(Q.when, Q()).then(function () {
    // if all promises resolved do some
});
```

Skip down to the "Sequences" section of the documentation. To copy it verbatim:

---

If you have a number of promise-producing functions that need to be run sequentially, you can of course do so manually:

```
return foo(initialVal).then(bar).then(baz).then(qux);
```

However, if you want to run a dynamically constructed sequence of functions, you'll want something like this:

```
var funcs = [foo, bar, baz, qux];

var result = Q(initialVal);
funcs.forEach(function (f) {
    result = result.then(f);
});
return result;
```

You can make this slightly more compact using reduce:

```
return funcs.reduce(function (soFar, f) {
    return soFar.then(f);
}, Q(initialVal));
```

Or, you could use th ultra-compact version:

```
return funcs.reduce(Q.when, Q());
```

---

There you have it. Straight from the horse's mouth.

Comment: oops!
very true!
sorry i've been doing a fast search using bad keywords (serie, serialize, chain ..) i didn't try "sequence" !
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sometime for loop is not that bad.

```js
for(const fn of asyncFns) {
  await fn()
}
```