# What is the purpose of the nested promise in this code?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to familiarise myself with Promises and how they work. While it's a new concept to me I'm relatively sure I can understand most of it. In particular I've been looking at the [BlueBird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) library and working my way through the examples. However there's one code snippet on the page that I can't quite wrap my head around.

```
Promise.promisifyAll(needle);
var options = {};

var current = Promise.resolve();
Promise.map(URLs, function(URL) {
    current = current.then(function () {
        return needle.getAsync(URL, options);
    });
    return current;
}).map(function(responseAndBody){
    return JSON.parse(responseAndBody[1]);
}).then(function (results) {
    return processAndSaveAllInDB(results);
}).then(function(){
    console.log('All Needle requests saved');
}).catch(function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

In this code I understand that the `needle` library is being promisified. I think I'd be right in saying that `current` is being set to an empty promise.

My question is around the

```
current = current.then(function () {
    return needle.getAsync(URL, options);
});
return current;
```

code. If needle has been promisified, what's the purpose of nesting it within another promise?

Comment: That's a *horrible* way of chaining the asynchronous actions. It [queues the `needle.getAsync` calls over the `URLs` array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23650478/1048572).

Comment: This mix of a `map` and a `reduce` should be used by its name: `scan`.

Comment: I certainly had my doubts that it was nice code. Thanks for clearing it up. If you want to put this as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Meh, actually it's not that horrible. Rather "tricky" and "non-obvious" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a dubious way of queuing the asynchronous calls and at the same time yielding them to the `map` function so that a promise for an array of all the results is produced.

So what does it do? The queuing alone is typically [done using `reduce`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23650478/1048572), that loop with the `current` accumulator does the same. It starts with the empty promise, and repeatedly chains a callback for every url in the array; like this code does:

```
var current = Promise.resolve().then(function() {
    return needle.getAsync(URL[0], options);
}).then(function() {
    return needle.getAsync(URL[1], options);
}).then(function() {
    return needle.getAsync(URL[2], options);
}) …
```

However, being used in a `map` loop it actually generates an array of single promises, like

```
var promises = [];
promises[0] = Promise.resolve().then(function() {
    return needle.getAsync(URL[0], options);
});
promises[1] = promises[0].then(function() {
    return needle.getAsync(URL[1], options);
});
promises[2] = promises[1].then(function() {
    return needle.getAsync(URL[2], options);
});
…
```

I would either use the `reduce` way, starting with `Promise.resolve([])` and adding to that result array step-by-step, or write a dedicated `scan` (or `mapAccum`, whatever you want to name it) function and use that in combination with `Promise.all`.

Or much better, just use Bluebird's built-in [`{concurrency: 1}` option for `Promise.map`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#option-concurrency)!

Comment: I thought it would have to be doing something like that. Thanks so much for clearing it up!

Answer (score 0):

Bergi wrote a good answer which you should read. Here is how I'd write that code using `.each`:

```
var get = Promise.promisify(needle.get);

Promise.each(URLs, get). // make the requests
       map(function(x){ return JSON.parse(x[1])} ). // parse response as json
       then(processAndSaveAllInDB).
       then(function(){ console.log("All Needle requests saved"); }).
```

Note you don't need the `catch` since Bluebird will find out about the unhandled rejection and report it for you in this case.

Usually when people do what the code above does they care about order although it was not guaranteed in the original code (map changed behaviour in bluebird 2 to be much faster but not guarantee queueing order).

Comment: Very interesting implementation of it. Thanks for the input!

Comment: How does this actually work? In the docs for `each`, I read "*Resolves to the original array unmodified, this method is meant to be used for side effects.*" So the results of the `get` calls aren't passed to those parser functions?

Comment: @Bergi oh woops, better get that changed in bluebird 3.0

Comment: @Bergi yes it will get changed in bluebird 3.0.. which is soon I just need to finish doing the website

Comment: @Esailija: But `each` for side effects sounds fine… I'd rather call it `mapSeries` or so if it returns the results for each element.

Comment: @Bergi simply changing the return value from useless to useful doesn't warrant a new method name, you can simply ignore the return value (like you always probably did) and it will function exactly the same