# Nodejs / Q : Chaining promises sequentially

Tags: node.js, promise, sequence, q, chain

I want to do something really simple, but i don't understand a little thing ...

```
var Q = require('q');

var funcs = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"];

function main(){

// really don't know how to chain sequentially here ...
    var result = Q();

    funcs.forEach(function (f) {
        result = treat(f).then(f);
    });

}

function treat(t){

    var deferred = Q.defer();

    setTimeout(function(){
        deferred.resolve("treated "+ t); 
    },2000);

    return deferred.promise;
}

main();
```

I would like each element of my funcs array to be "treated" sequentially, the output would then be something like :

```
treated first
//2 seconds later
treated second
//2 seconds later
treated third
//2 seconds later
treated fourth
```

I cannot achieve that :( it should be simple , i don't catch something :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Judging from your example, I would assume that you already saw [Sequences part of Q readme](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#sequences), but failed to understand it.

Original example used "waterfall" model, when the output of each function passed as an input to the next one:

```
var funcs = [foo, bar, baz, qux];

var result = Q(initialVal);
funcs.forEach(function (f) {
    result = result.then(f);
});
return result;
```

But you just want to execute all our functions in sequence, so you could simply bind each function with its variables:

```
var args = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"];

var result = Q();
args.forEach(function (t) {
    result = result.then(treat.bind(null, t));
});
return result;
```

In my example `treat` function will be called 4 times sequentially, and `result` promise will be resolved with the value of latest `treat` call (results of all previous calls will be ignored).

The trick is that `.then` method accepts a handler which will be called after current promise will be resolved and returns a new promise. So, you should pass to `.then` a function which should be called on the next step of your execution chain. `treat.bind(null, t)` binds `treat` function with attribute `t`. In other words, it returns a new function, which will invoke `treat`, passing `t` as its first argument.