# Page Object Pattern asynchronous using node.js selenium

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, selenium-webdriver

I am having a hard time trying to adjust to asynchronous using node.js. I ran into an issue when using selenium-webdriver and the page object pattern. I feel like somethings have to be synchronous when doing automation testing or your tests will fail because you clicked a button before inserting data. I am having an issue similar to this. I want to add an employee and then search for the employee, but the search for employee is performing before add employee.

```
var employee = new Employee('grimlek', 'Charles', 'Sexton', 'TitleTitle',
    'Upper Management', 'Company Admin', 'Contractor', '-7', 'Remote',
    '05212016', '3369407787', '3368791234', 'charles@example.com',
    'charles.sexton', 'Skype', 'abcdefgh');

driver.get('https://website.com/login')
.then(function() {
     //This behaves as intended
     loginPage.login('company.admin', 'password') })
.then(function() {
      //Add employee
      employeePage.addEmployee(employee) })
.then(function() {
     //Search for employee after employee is added 
     employeePage.searchEmployee(employee)});
```

EmployeePage Object

```
var EmployeePage = function (driver) {

this.addEmployee = function (employee) {
    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('button[class=\'btn btn-default\']')).then(function (element) {
        //
        //Search employee function is done before the line below this
        //
        element.click();
    }).then(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('employee_username')).then(function (element) {
                element.sendKeys(employee.username);
            });

            driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('employee_first_name')).then(function (element) {
                element.sendKeys(employee.firstName);
            });

            driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('employee_last_name')).then(function (element) {
                element.sendKeys(employee.lastName);
            });

            driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('employee_title_id')).then(function (element) {
                element.sendKeys(employee.title);
            });

            driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('employee_role')).then(function (element) {
                element.sendKeys(employee.role);
            });
        }, 5000);
    });
//
//
//Search employee should occur when the thread leaves the function
//
};

this.searchEmployee = function (employee) {
    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('input[class=\'form-control ng-pristine ng-valid\']')).then(function(element) {
       element.sendKeys(employee.firstName + ' ' + employee.lastName); 
    });
};
```

};

module.exports = EmployeePage;

I know that both searchEmployee and addEmployee functions don't return a promise and I am trying to chain them with the .then function. I do believe this is sorta my problem but I need help with how it should be done and not how I can rig it. Should I use callbacks? I have worked on this problem for going on four hours now and I have tried googling and doing research on various topics. If I didn't provide enough code please let me know and I will provide a simplified runnable example.

Comment: i have deleted asyn and async libs from node_module and install npm again, it happens with me everytime I am initiating the debug mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A laudable goal is to make each test independent. If a change is made to the application (e,g, bug fix) only the impacted test(s) need to be executed. Also, it makes moving to grid thinkable.

But this is difficult to achieve in practice.  Your test has to include all tests needed to satisfy the prerequisites.

[Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/) has feature files that include scenarios Each scenario is a test.  Scenarios are executed in the order they are listed in the feature file. So one way to organize things is to include all the prerequisite scenarios before your test in a feature file,  You can add [tag(s)](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags) before the Feature statement so that when you execute that tag the entire feature file runs.  Perhaps the first scenario resets (a subset of) the database to a know state.

The trick would be to run features in parallel on multiple machines.  If you point those multiple clients to the same server beware that the features should not create or update overlapping entities that could collide when written to the database by the server. E.g. "What do you mean that user 'tom' already exists?"  Each feature needs to create a unique user name.

Comment: is promise chaining normal in node.js? Every solution I develop I end up with nested promises chained one after another to the end of the test.

Comment: Does this [Nodejs / Q : Chaining promises sequentially](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27322994/nodejs-q-chaining-promises-sequentially) help?

Comment: Also take a look at this [slide set].(http://pt.slideshare.net/alan_parkinson/cross-browser-testing-java-script-47642180)

Answer (score 0):

The way of approach using cucumber is to divide you steps for every individual operation.

Ex:

```
Given I am on XYZ Form
And I provide all form details
```

In above case, for step `And I provide all form details` you will be including all the fields in step definition and start filling the fields say name, last name, address in single step definition.

Instead of this we should divide the step for every individual field like:

```
Given I am on XYZ Form
And I provide name details in XYZ Form
And I provide last name details in XYZ Form
And I provide address details in XYZ Form
```

And then we will be writing 3 step definition which of course will be running sequentially.

You may feel that the typing work got increased and step definitions got increased unnecessarily, but this will actually help you when a field gets removed from the application itself, you will be only needing to delete related step from future file.
More over you can easily test validation for fields by just commenting one of the step in your feature file.
And your code will be more easy to maintain as every steps is working independently.

And of course sequential work will get achieved.

Comment: The OP didn't mention Cucumber.  Still I'm interested since I am trying to use Cucumber with node.  Even with separating steps out, none of my asynch calls to the selenium daemon are executing.  Each cucumber step seems to queue up the command and move on before it finishes.  The program ends before some of the asynch requests are even sent to the server.

Comment: I believe you are creating respective/individual step definition for every step in feature.

Comment: this may interest you 
https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/12/17/asynchronous-testing-protractor-angular/