# Making multi callback synchronized with jQuery $.when

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, synchronization, jquery-deferred

This is my sample code:

```js
function out(msg)
{
  $('#output').append(msg + '<br>');
}

var myDeferred = [];
$.each([8, 3, 4, 6, 9, 15, 7, 1], function (index, time)
{
  myDeferred.push($.Deferred(function(dfd)
  {
    setTimeout(function ()
    {
      out(time);
      dfd.resolve();
    }, time * 1000);
  }).promise());
});

$.when.apply($, myDeferred).then(function ()
{
  out('all is done');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

This output **"1 3 4 6 7 8 9 15 all is done"**, all callback are called at the same time.

### But I want **"8 3 4 6 9 15 7 1 all is done"**, all callback are called one after the other.

Someone can help me ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clarify what you want? Do you want 8 seconds to pass, print a message, then 3 seconds to pass, print a message, ... ?

Comment: What do you mean "all callbacks are called at the same time" - they have different `time` values and different timeouts?

Comment: @JuniorCompressor you have a good answer, but is it possible with $.Deferred ?

Comment: @Bergi when I say that, I speak about the callback in the array myDeferred, not the callback on the setTimeout

Comment: If you do want the delay to be shown, don't use `$.when` on array, use it on each `$Defered` individually. Not entirely clear what your expectations are

Comment: @dtcSearch: Yes, of course `$.each` is synchronous. Promises don't change that. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18386753/1048572) on how to *chain* the array callbacks

Comment: ok, thant for your help :)
I can't up you're reputation, but when I've the 15 :) I do that ;)
@JuniorCompressor you're anwser is approved!

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the link, I've already read that, but right now, I understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that each callback timeout is activated almost at the same time. You can do the following though:

```
function out(msg)
{
  $('#output').append(msg + '<br>');
}

function foo(index, callback) {
  var time = array[index];
  out(time);
  if (index == array.length - 1)
    callback();
  else
    setTimeout(foo, time * 1000, index + 1, callback);
}

var array = [8, 3, 4, 6, 9, 15, 7, 1];
foo(0, function ()
{
  out('all is done');
});
```

Using promises:

```
function out(msg)
{
  $('#output').append(msg + '<br>');
}

var myDeferred = [];
$.each([8, 3, 4, 6, 9, 15, 7, 1], function (index, time)
{
  myDeferred.push($.Deferred(function(dfd)
  {
    var f = function() {
      out(time);
      dfd.resolve();
    }
    if (index > 0)
      myDeferred[index - 1].done(function() { setTimeout(f, time * 1000); });
    else 
      setTimeout(f, time * 1000);
  }).promise());
});

$.when.apply($, myDeferred).then(function ()
{
  out('all is done');
});
```

Comment: defeats the purpose of trying to use promises which seems to be what OP is trying to grasp. In an ajax situation there is no guarantee that data would be returned in same  order as requests are made

Comment: also , this solution requires prior process to have completed before new one is initiated, takes far longer that way

Comment: Yes but I think is what @dtcSearch asks

Comment: this is my answser, just, @JuniorCompressor more close of my demo ? Is possible ?

Comment: @charlietfl it's not a speed problem, it's a demo code, i've use it in case of indexedDB multi-insert (for not block the client browser with multi-insert at the same time)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of logging your response within the initial loop, pass your data to `resolve()` then inside `when()` you will receive the array of resolved data. Loop over that array instead and all will be in order

```
var myDeferred = [];
$.each([8, 3, 4, 6, 9, 15, 7, 1], function (index, time)
{
  myDeferred.push($.Deferred(function(dfd)
  {
    setTimeout(function ()
    {
      /* pass data to resolve()*/
      dfd.resolve(time);
    }, time * 100);
  }).promise());
});

$.when.apply($, myDeferred).then(function ()
{
    /* loop over arguments */
    $.each(arguments,function(_, time){
        out(time);
    });
    console.log(arguments);
    out('all is done');
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rg7zc6nn/)**</kbd>

Comment: I want callbacks on array myDeferred not called at the same time, here, it's just the result in the right order, but I speak more about the way to do that. thanks for this demo, you resolve (with arguments) an other of my problem but not this one

Comment: so based on start time 0 , what exactly do you want to have happen?